# Trouble installing Rails App on MediaTemple?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mediatemple

I am having some trouble installing an app on MediaTemple's Grid Servers... I'm deploying with cap and github... everything seems to go ok with those, but the app won't start up.  There seems to be a problem with my database.yml file?  I've checked for space errors and those all look good.

Here is a copy of the console when I try and start from there:

```
XXXXXXXXX.com@n11:/home/65633/containers/rails/GDB/current$ script/server RAILS_ENV="production" --trace
** Ruby version is not up-to-date; loading cgi_multipart_eof_fix
=> Booting Mongrel (use 'script/server webrick' to force WEBrick)
server: invalid option: --trace
=> Rails 2.2.2 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
** Starting Mongrel listening at 0.0.0.0:3000
** Starting Rails with development environment...
config.gem: Unpacked gem geokit-1.4.1 in vendor/gems has no specification file. Run 'rake gems:refresh_specs' to fix this.
Exiting
/home/65633/data/rubygems/gems/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in `establish_connection': development database is not configured (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/gems/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:53:in `establish_connection'
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:392:in `initialize_database'
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:139:in `process'
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:112:in `send'
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:112:in `run'
    from /nfs/c04/h03/mnt/65633/containers/rails/GDB/releases/20090830045026/config/environment.rb:15
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
     ... 24 levels...
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/server.rb:49
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

Here is the mongrel log:

```
** Daemonized, any open files are closed.  Look at log/mongrel.pid and log/mongrel.log for info.
** Starting Mongrel listening at 0.0.0.0:2017
** Starting Rails with production environment...
/home/65633/data/rubygems/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': /home/65633/containers/rails/GDB/releases/20090830060044/app/controllers/administration_controller.rb:159: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/gems/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:155:in `require'
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/gems/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:262:in `require_or_load'
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/gems/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:221:in `depend_on'
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/gems/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:133:in `require_dependency'
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:368:in `load_application_classes'
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:367:in `each'
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:367:in `load_application_classes'
     ... 17 levels...
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/gems/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-linux/bin/../lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/gems/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-linux/bin/mongrel_rails:281
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/gems/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
    from /home/65633/data/rubygems/gems/bin/mongrel_rails:19
```

mtr start error

```
application started, but pid file was not found, check 'mtr status'
```

Answer (score 0):

The command `script/server RAILS_ENV="production"` clearly doesn't start Mongrel with the development environment, as you can see from this log line from your first excerpt:

```
** Starting Rails with development environment...
```

Furthermore, if you try to run `RAILS_ENV=production script/server`, does the application start without any gem related errors? That's what I would check.

As for the error in the second logfile, I'm not really sure. What is in line 159 of your administration_controller.rb?